# Div does not get over PDF in IE8 / IE9 but works on FF & Chrome

Tags: html, pdf, z-index

I want to get my DIV over a PDF.
This example works fine with FF but does not work with IE 8 / 9. note: this is the same result whatever PDF pointed too.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="position:absolute;z-index:1000;background-color:pink;z-index:1000">
I'm over PDF
</div>
<iframe src="http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf" style="width:100%;height:100%;z-index:0">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like others have been looking for a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593176/div-layer-on-top-of-pdf) and failed so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/help/sutra56313.html)
You basically need to insert and empty iframe below the div but overlaying the PDF and play with Z-index : pdf (1), background iframe (50), content div (100).

Comment: The link you provided gives me a 404 error.  Can you post a working code example please?