# PDF in iFrame overlaps jQuery dialog box, z-index not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, iframe, z-index

I tried many option to fix the z-index issue of PDF iFrame overlapping jQuery Dialog box, but still its not working.

similar to "[Iframe issue when i open pdf dialog box goes behind pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084179/iframe-issue-when-i-open-pdf-dialog-box-goes-behind-pdf)" issue, 
I am having the same issue **in IE**, here is the screenshot of my issue:

[image]

Below is the jQuery code of which generates the dialog box:-

```
           $("#cancelSessionButton").click(function () {
                $("#sessionReason").dialog("open");
                $("#pdf").hide();
            });


            $("#sessionReason").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Submit": function () {
                        .......

                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $("#pdf").show();
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#cancelSessionButton").click(function () {
                $("#sessionReason").dialog("open");
                $("#pdf").hide();
            });
```

Here is the HTML from which the iFrame is generating:

```
          <div id="pdf">

            <iframe id="pdfIframe" name="pdfIframe" src="pdf.html" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1">
                 Your browser doesn't support inline frames.
            </iframe>
        </div>
```

PDF.html code:

```
<body>
    <object data="lorem.pdf" type="application/pdf">
        <p>It appears you don't have Adobe Reader or PDF support in this web browser.
            <br/>
            <a href="lorem.pdf">Click here to download the PDF</a> OR <a href="http://get.adobe.com/reader/" target="_blank">Click here to install Adobe Reader</a></p>
        <embed id="pdfDocument" src="lorem.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
   </object>
</body>
```

let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest!!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to display a simple div over a PDF viewer in IE, however, maybe You can do some kind of workaround (like hiding the pdf viewer when the dialog box is shown).

Comment: as an alternate m doing that only... showing and hiding pdf based on dialog box open and close

Comment: I suppose it's the easiest way to workaround this issue.

Comment: yeah... but still wanted to check if there is any solution for the same.. just in case my workaround is not acceptable.. you see ;-)

Comment: I see. There is a kind of workaround described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/711888/232530, but it's rather for masking the pdf than for displaying something above it.

Comment: agree... let me try is this help!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution by using an iframe hack (see this question for the explanation of the hack: [z-index does not work in Internet Explorer with pdf in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911428/z-index-does-not-work-in-internet-explorer-with-pdf-in-iframe)).

Since JQuery 1.9, you can extend the JQuery `ui.dialog` component. The solution is to add an `iframe` to the `.ui-dialog` DOM element. You can do this way:

```
$.widget( "ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
    _parentInit: $.ui.dialog.prototype._init,

    _init: function() {
        this._parentInit();

        $("<iframe src=\"about:blank\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"position:absolute; top:0;left:0; width:100%;height:100%;z-index:-1;\"></iframe>").appendTo(this.element.parent());
    }
});
```

The Javascript code must be executed before initializing any dialog. It means, it should be in the `head` part and should not wait on the DOM readiness.

Every JQuery dialog will have the `iframe` added automatically which solves the layering problem with Adobe Plugin in IE. I tested the solution with IE11.