# Position absolute div displays below PDF file

Tags: html, css, pdf, iframe, position

I have an iframe which has a PDF document. I also have a div that I want to display over that PDF file.

**HTML CODE**

```
<iframe width="200" height="200" src="abc.pdf" style="border:1px solid #000"></iframe>
<div style="width:200px; height:50px; border:1px solid #000; background:red; position:absolute; top:60px; left:60px"></div>
```

In Mozilla, this div is displayed properly over a PDF document. But in IE(8, 9, 10) it is displayed below PDF.

Please let me know if I can do something about it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Q6nF6/

Comment: Does the z-index have any control over the positioning? (i.e. layering above the pdf document).  If it's any use, [I did find this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593176/div-layer-on-top-of-pdf).

Answer (score 1):

for absolute positioning to work the parent element must have positioning so make your parent element position: relative;