# <p:submenu> displayed behind <p:media>

Tags: layout, jsf-2, primefaces, media

I tried [complex layout](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutComplex.jsf), and in the center layout I have `<p:media>` which shows a PDF file.

The problem I faced, is that the sub-menu appears behind my PDF file.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: @BalusC do you have an idea how to fix this problem ?

Comment: This can't easily be fixed. See also among others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593176/div-layer-on-top-of-pdf Note that the problem is not in JSF, but in HTML+CSS. Ultimately, JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML/CSS code generator.

Comment: The problem cannot be fixed @BalusC !